# Add countdown timer to <td> based on text of other <td> in the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add a countdown timer (using this one http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) to a td based on the text of another td within the same table using jQuery.

For example my table looks like this below and I want to add the timer to the time_remaining td if the status td contains the text "Received".

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="status">Completed</td>
       <td class="time_received"></td>
       <td class="time_remaining"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="status">Received</td>
        <td class="time_received"></td>
        <td class="time_remaining"></td>
    </tr>        
</table>
```

And my jQuery currently looks like this below, but I'm using `$(this).next()` which will only add the timer to the time_received td, but I need to add it to the time_remaining td, what can I use instead of `.next()`? Any help would be appreciated.

```
 var newCount = new Date(); 
 newCount.setMinutes(newCount.getMinutes() + 30);
 $('td.status:contains(Received)').each(function() {
   $(this).next().countdown({
        until: newCount, 
        format: 'M',
        layout: "{mn} min"
        });
​});​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a selector to next and use an index to specify which - in your case there is just one sibling with the time_remaining class, so it's the same

```
.next(".time_remaining")[0]
```

Alternatively, if you always want the second sibling you could do

```
.nextAll()[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

`.next()` has an overload that takes a selector, so you can use:

```
var newCount = new Date(); 
newCount.setMinutes(newCount.getMinutes() + 30);
$('td.status:contains(Received)').each(function() {
    $(this).next(".time_remaining").countdown({
        until: newCount, 
        format: 'M',
        layout: "{mn} min"
    });
});
```

See here: [JQuery .next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

Comment: Cheers for the reply,  I had already tried that in my app and in a jfiddle and the timer does not appear in the <time_remaining> td ?.

Comment: if I use this it works $(this).nextAll(".time_remaining") but just using .next(".time_remaining") doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use .next(), just pass in the selector for the td you want.

```
$(this).next('.time_remaining').countdown({});
```

Check out the documentation for more information:
http://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: Thanks, but this doesnt seem to append the timer to the time_remaining  td ? .